# using statsmodels with a groupby

Tags: python, pandas, statsmodels

Consider this simple example

```
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.formula.api as sm

df = pd.DataFrame({'Y' : [1,2,3,4,5,6,7],
                   'X' : [2,3,4,5,6,3,2],
                   'group' : ['a','a','a','a','b','b','b']})

df
Out[99]: 
   Y  X group
0  1  2     a
1  2  3     a
2  3  4     a
3  4  5     a
4  5  6     b
5  6  3     b
6  7  2     b
```

I would like to run a regression by group. I only have found very old answers or solutions with a loop. I just wonder why the very simple:

```
df.groupby('group').agg(lambda x: sm.ols(formula = 'Y ~ X', data = x))
PatsyError: Error evaluating factor: NameError: name 'X' is not defined
    Y ~ X
```

does not work. Can we do better with the latest versions of Pandas (1.2.3)?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `apply` function -

```
df.groupby('group').apply(lambda x: sm.ols(formula = 'Y ~ X', data = x))
```

**Output**

```
group
a    <statsmodels.regression.linear_model.OLS objec...
b    <statsmodels.regression.linear_model.OLS objec...
dtype: object
```

You now have a model for every group fit and ready to go.

Comment: pretty simple, actually. thanks! what would you suggest to extract parameter values and t stats all at once?

Comment: yes absolutely! In which case you would have to handle the output of the `apply` function accordingly of course. You can use apply function on top of this output (simple apply, not a groupby apply) and extract objects/do more stuff like your t stats